# Div se oculta al disminuir el ancho del navegador

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Estoy editando los estilos de está pagina web: http://www.ishameetings.cl/

El problema es que al disminuir el ancho del navegador el div llamado "site-top-bar-right" no muestra su contenido, como se muestra en la siguiente captura:

[image: Div con un ancho pequeño]

[image: Div con un ancho grande]

Cualquier sugerencia o ayuda es bienvenida.

**Codigo Html**

```
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header site-header-one bg-left header-nosocial header-boxed-in">
        <div class="site-top-bar site-pad">
            <div class="site-container">

                <div class="site-top-bar-left">
                  <!--

                  <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                  -->
                    <a href="http://www.isha.net">Visit ISHA.net</a>
                </div>



                <div class="site-top-bar-right">



                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                      <a href="mailto:%63%6fn&#116;&#097;c&#116;&#064;%69s%68%61%6d&#101;%65&#116;&#105;n%67%73%2e&#099;&#108;">contact@ishameetings.cl</a>

                  <!--

                          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                      +569 0000 0000                                        -->

                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;

                    JOIN US IN SANTIAGO



                </div>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bar site-pad">
            <div class="site-container">
                <div class="header-bar-inner">
                    <div class="site-branding">


                      <div class="logo_isha">
                        <a href="http://ishameetings.cl/"><img src="http://ishameetings.cl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/logo.png"/></a>
```

**CSS**

```
  .site-header-one .site-top-bar-left {
      background-color: #D7565D !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  }

  .site-header-one .site-top-bar-right {
      background-color: #D7565D !important;
      color: #ffffff;
      float: right;

  }

  .site-header-one .site-top-bar {
      background-color: #D7565D !important;
  }

  .site-header .header-bar .site-container {
      margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
```

Comment: Hola america. Si vas a mostrar Código, que sea en formato texto en vez de imagen. Es mucho mas claro, se puede copiar y tarda menos en cargar (para aquellos con poca cobertura movil)

Comment: Desde el inspector del navegador web, en el caso del ancho reducido que oculta el div, si desplegas con la flechecita el div, hay contenido? Porque por lo que parece es que se oculta el contenido. ya que el div continua marcandose en azul en la pantalla.

Comment: Si hablas del slider, el diseño responsivo es lo que hace que sea adaptable y no se desborde, si aun asi quieres mostrar las imagenes en ventana pequeña prueba buscar las medias queries de css estan definidas por @media{} y busca la clase de el slider, o bien comenta la class="wds_slideshow_image_0"

Comment: Y estás seguro de que ese es todo el CSS que estás cargando? No hay boostrap en el html generado?

Comment: Gracias, por agregar el código, además he descartado el uso de las media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto está sucediendo porque estás implementando de este estilo:

```
.site-header-one .site-top-bar {
    height: 30px !important;
}
```

Cuando se supone que es así, sin lo `height: 30px !important;`:

```
.site-header-one .site-top-bar {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Y por qué he cambiado la propiedad `height: 30px !important;` para `padding-bottom: 2px;`, porque me doy cuenta que tienes otra propriedad `box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;` en la clase - `.site-header-one .site-top-bar`, para dar una sombra à la barra que despues no se ha notar se no tener esta `padding`.

Comment: Gracias Cʜᴜɴ, ¡diste justo en el clavo! Borré la altura de 30px y se solucionó el problema.